# Using descriptors or properties with classmethod

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, class-method, python-descriptors

I've seen many answers to that question, all of them saying it's impossible to use a property with a classmethod, but the following code works:

```
class A:
    @classmethod
    @property
    def hello(cls):
        print(1234)

>>> A.hello
1234
```

Why and how does it work?

Running on CPython 3.9.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting in Python 3.9, classmethods trigger the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html). From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#class-methods):

> The code path for `hasattr(obj, '__get__')` was added in Python 3.9 and makes it possible for `classmethod()` to support chained decorators.

Surprisingly, diving a bit deeper into the subject will show you that `classmethod` triggers the descriptor `__get__` with the class itself as the instance:

```
class Descriptor:
  def __get__(self, instance, owner):
    print(instance, owner)
  def __set__(self, value, owner):
    print(value, owner)

class A:
  regular = Descriptor()
  clsmethod = classmethod(Descriptor())

>>> A.regular
None <class '__main__.A'>
>>> A.clsmethod
<class '__main__.A'> None
```

I'm guessing they made it specifically to support descriptors such as `@property`, as accessing them through the class returns the property itself:

```
class B:
  @property
  def prop(self):
    print(self)

>>> B.__dict__["prop"].__get__(None, 1234)
<property object at 0x000001BEEB635630>
>>> B.__dict__["prop"].__get__(1234, None)
1234
```

It's a bit unintuitive and turns the descriptor protocol clunky if you wish to support both `classmethod` and normal descriptors, as you have to check if the `owner` is `None`.

Keep in mind however,  `__set__` is **not called** (as the descriptor protocol doesn't call it when setting class attributes),  making you **unable** to use `@property.setter`:

```
>>> A.regular = 1234
>>> A.regular
1234
>>> A.clsmethod = 1234
>>> A.clsmethod
1234
```

Comment: Wouldn't that code path run for all types of descriptors including normal functions since they all implement \_\_get\_\_? Is the methodtype code path only kept for callables that aren't descriptors?